# How to transliterate 中文 in Mandarin pronunciation to German?

Tags: pronunciation

I am working on an art project where I would like to collect hundreds of different transliterations of 「中文」 zhōng wén in Mandarin Chinese. (Pronunciation available here: [https://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/de/中文](https://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/de/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87))

How can I transliterate zhōng wén in German? (For example, "zhong wen" would be the closest pronunciation in English.)

Comment: I suppose normally you'd use Pinyin to transliterate, except when you expect your audience to know nothing about Chinese, at all: then you'd probably use something like "Schong Wen", but can't remember having seen something like this actually done. There's plenty of consonants in Chinese for which there are not exact equivalents in German.

Answer (score 1):

If it's about written transliteration, then the answer for basically all latin-based target scripts will be the way it's done in Pinyin. This is not dependent on the target script.

If it's about pronounciation, the answer is either "none available" for non-learners, because there's no way for Germans to derive any pronounciation from the symbols without a-priori knowledge about them, or "almost like in Mandarin" for those who have or are learning Mandarin, where the goal will be to get as close as possible to the original pronounciation.

I took a couple of semesters of Mandarin in university, and the teacher would go to any length to get us to pronounce the tones and syllables correctly. This was basically the main part of training to *speak* Mandarin. Hence, "none at all" or "more or less correct" for pronounciation.

As for making the Pinyin transliteration more accessible to native German speakers (because again you need a-priori knowledge to map the tones to sounds), like Janka tried in his answer, I'm sceptical this makes much sense. Despite being used in the name of the car brand, the average reader will not know what to do about the ë when encountering it in an unfamiliar setting like a homebrew transliteration of a Chinese word. Many simplify the pronounciation of the brand to "Zitröhn", or alternatively just forget about the trema when writing.

Answer (score 0):

I hear **Tschung Uën.**

The trema on the e is needed as German speakers otherwise would pronounce Ue as ü as in https://translate.google.com/#de/zh-CN/%C3%BCber. The letter *ë* isn't much used in German but widely understood as it is part of the car brand name *Citroën*.

*Tschung Wenn* is also possible but further away from the Chinese pronounciation: https://translate.google.com/#de/zh-CN/Tschung%20Wenn